# Google NLP Entities Returning Wikipedia link as German instead of English

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl

I've been trying to use the Entities Analyze API call for Google NLP and strangely enough, it keeps returning links to Wikipedia in German. Any idea how to resolve this?

You can see the try the API page does the same thing. https://cloud.google.com/natural-language

[Google NLP Try The API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73hms.png)

Thoughts? I've tried passing in the Language for the AnalyzeEntities call and it still returns Wikipedia results in different languages.

Comment: This issue has already been reported and is being worked on. Further updates regarding this issue will be posted in this [issue tracker thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/230777156). You can `STAR` the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).